# Login form in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I´m create a simple login in flutter. This login connect to a API. For do this I retrieve inputs value and send to a method, but return

> type '_InternalLinkedHashMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map'

This is my model

```
class Login {
  final String usuario, password;

  Login({this.usuario, this.password});

  factory Login.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Login(
      usuario: json['usuario'] as String,
      password: json['password'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my main class

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:igota/screens/home/home_page.dart';
import 'package:igota/model/login.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String tag = 'login-page';
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => new _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final userValue = new TextEditingController();
  final passwordValue = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final logo = Hero(
      tag: 'hero',
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        radius: 48.0,
        child: Image.asset('assets/logo.png'),
      ),
    );

    final username = TextFormField(
      controller: userValue,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Introduce un nombre';
        }
      },
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      autofocus: false,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Usuario',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    final password = TextFormField(
      controller: passwordValue,
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          return 'Introduce una contraseña';
        }
      },
      autofocus: false,
      obscureText: true,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        hintText: 'Contraseña',
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 20.0, 10.0),
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0)),
      ),
    );

    Widget _buildLoginButton(BuildContext context) {
      return Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
        child: Material(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          child: MaterialButton(
            minWidth: 200.0,
            height: 42.0,
            onPressed: () {
              fetchPost(userValue, passwordValue);
              //final snackBar = SnackBar(
              //    content: Text(
              //  'Usuario/Contraseña incorrecto',
              //  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              //));
              //Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(HomePage.tag);
              }
            },
            color: Colors.blue[300],
            child: Text('Entrar', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    final forgotLabel = FlatButton(
      child: Text(
        '¿Contraseña olvidada?',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
      ),
      onPressed: () {},
    );

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Center(
                child: Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: ListView(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0),
                children: <Widget>[
                  logo,
                  SizedBox(height: 48.0),
                  username,
                  SizedBox(height: 8.0),
                  password,
                  SizedBox(height: 24.0),
                  _buildLoginButton(context),
                  forgotLabel
                ],
              ),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}

//Test
Future<Login> fetchPost(user, pass) async {
  Map headers = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
  };
  final response = await http.post(
      'URL',
      body: {"usuario": user.text, "password": pass.text},
      headers: headers);
  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  return Login.fromJson(responseJson);
}
```

So i need to return response and check if correct or incorrect to show snackbar. I don't know exactly what i'm doing right or wrong :$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the type of `headers` like this:

```
Map<String, String> headers = {
  'Content-type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
};
```

EDIT: You need to use `json.encode` on the body of a request with `'Content-type': 'application/json'` as well.

EDIT2:

```
Future<Login> fetchPost(user, pass) async {
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
    };
    final response = await http.post(
        'URL',
        body: json.encode({"usuario": user.text, "password": pass.text}),
        headers: headers);
    final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    return Login.fromJson(responseJson);
  }
```

Comment: Doesn´t work, return 'Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json".

Comment: @ElHombreSinNombre Well, that's a separate bug from the HashMap one. I edited my answer with regards to that.

Comment: ¿What about if login fails? ¿How can i do error handling? ¿With try catch?